# Change QHeaderView space buffer

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview

I have a slightly customized QTableView showing a model that I've developed. When I instruct the TableView to resizeColumnToContents, I end up with an extra buffer of about 20 pixels on either side of the column's text. This is major overkill for my table, as you can see below.

[image: Screenshot showing the unnecessary buffer]

The user can manually resize the column to remove that buffer, but it's annoying when there are a lot of columns.

How might I change this buffer/margin size programmatically? I'm willing to use delegates, sizeHints, styleSheets, whatever it takes. I just can't find where this value is set.

**Edit:** Stepping through [QHeaderView::sizeHint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW8FN.png)() and [QHeaderView::sectionSizeFromContents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sectionSizeFromContents)() showed me that this is happening because I have sorting enabled (line 2588 of qheaderview.cpp). Disabling sorting removed the horizontal buffer.

Why on earth would the sizehint add a buffer of the header's height to its width if sorting is enabled? The sort indicator appears *above* the header (see below). The sort indicator has no relevance to the required column width. Weird.

[image]

I can't see a way around this other than implementing my own QHeaderView class. Is there a better way?

Comment: What QStyle is your app using?  All of the styles I've seen have the sort-arrow displayed at the right side of the column-header rectangle, which is why the sizehint is adding space for it there.

Comment: Good question. I'm running on Windows 7 x64, so I think it's defaulting to the Vista style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Qt4 that got fixed in Qt5. It's leaving extra space for a sort indicator that's not there when using the Vista style.

Implementing my own QHeaderView subclass was the only way to fix this in qt 4.8.

```
QSize MyHeaderView::sectionSizeFromContents(int logicalIndex) const
{
    QSize sz = QHeaderView::sectionSizeFromContents(logicalIndex);

    //Qt 4.8.x workaround to remove horizontal spacing from sort indicator with vista style
    if(isSortIndicatorShown())
    {
        auto style = qApp->style();
        if(orientation() == Qt::Horizontal && style->objectName() == "windowsvista")
        {
            int margin = style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_HeaderMargin, 0, this);
            sz.rwidth() -= margin + sz.height();
        }
    }

    return sz;
}
```

I tested this on Windows 7 and 10 using Qt 5.11.1 and the workaround is no longer necessary. I'm not sure when, exactly, it was fixed.